# How long to wait before reposting an edited version of a closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked a question which was not proper because it was too specific and could have been reasonably interpreted as asking for legal advice. The question was closed by moderators. I edited the question so that it is a proper question for the site and I am now waiting for it to be opened again.

Of course, I understand that moderators have their own priorities and my edited question might be voted on in a day, a month, or never.

In such a situation, how long should one wait before deleting the original closed question and re-asking the proper question for the site?

Comment: I [answered](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/86449/18505) a similar question you posted days earlier. The additional details in your subsequent, currently closed post would not lead to a different conclusion. Why would you need to get the later post reopened? Only the reference to "financial year" in art. 14.2 *might* allow a costs overview to cover a period longer than a year, but that is irrelevant if the landlord failed to provide you with the costs overview before expiration of the deadline: the first semester of the calendar year.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Thanks for your answer. My previous question didn't capture all the details and it was a question about voiding the article in question due to parties implicitly agreeing(?) on it, although I agree that also in my opinion it shouldn't change the interpretation of the rest. My closed question was initially improper, but after editing I got to a proper question that is not about changing a contract, but about the interpretation of a text that may be found in a contract. Indeed, in the previous question, the answer partially covered this as well, but the focus was still on voiding.

Comment: Reposting an edited version of a closed question can result in automatic bans.  See discussions on [Meta.SE].  E.g., [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302687/241697), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268100/241697), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176971/241697).

Answer (score 4):

It's in the Reopen queue.  Don't repost it, as that would be an attempt to circumvent Stack Exchange processes.

NB, as of this moment:

- The question already has two of five required re-open votes.
- No moderator voted to either close or reopen this question; all votes have been by "regular" users.

Comment: thanks for this info and thanks for checking my particular situation. I was aware of the stack Exchange process, and this is exactly the reason I didn't repost.  At the same time, my intention now was to ask a question that may help others, not necessarily only me. Given this, your answer helps me, but doesn't really answer the question. If an edited question stays closed because perhaps there is no interest of people voting on it. How long should one wait before reposting the new re-edited question?

Comment: If there are not enough users working the review queues then that should be raised as an issue on Meta, because that means the Stack Exchange model isn't working on this stack.  But that's something the Mods and CMs monitor so don't expect to find that to be the case.  (It is not the case at present on Law.SE)

Comment: I would not have even known to raise this issue the way you put it. Moreover, I would find it unfair that a question would be blocked in limbo out of principle, when one could easily post the new version of the question. At the same time, I agree this should not be abused to repost questions in the hope they wouldn't be caught. Nevertheless massively edited questions are almost different questions. That's the point of editing. That's why a mindful timeframe would be useful in this situations, as a plan B, and I was wondering if there is already a policy, or a common practice about it.

Comment: Moreover, questions not being voted on is a kind of a problem for stackexchange/moderators and a different kind of a problem for a user, although they are the same problem. The first has the solution you explained in the previous comment, but that may not solve the issue for the user, if e.g. the review qeueus would take months to fix, while a question can be reposted in a week, or two or a month and if the question is proper, it shouldn't cause an issue for the site, but it would solve the problem for the user.

Comment: @Andrei you're talking about changing a policy that applies network-wide.  If you want to propose that you should do so on [Meta.SE].

Comment: @Andrei "*massively edited questions are almost different questions.*" Yes, but that is not the case with the post at issue. Much of that post repeats a question you asked and were answered (in detail and with citation of sources) earlier. As a user who is inclined to reopen posts and upvoted your previous one (dated Nov. 18), I find such repetition discouraging. It suggests that it is pointless for us to spend any effort on your questions because you will end up asking them again anyway.

Comment: @feetwet I do not want to propose anything. I was clearly just asking because I am interested to better understand the process.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I am sorry, but I am very confused about what you are talking about. You must have misread something I wrote because I cannot make sense of what you are saying. When I said massively edited questions, I was referring to the example of a closed bad question and a good question. I was not referring to any of my particular questions, but to a situation. I am also clueless of where you got it that I intended to repost my question. I am obviously aware of the possibility, yet, without knowing the policy, I understood of why it's bad, and then I specifically asked about the policy.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I didn't have enough characters in the previous comment. I am really appreciating that you answered my question about voiding an article of a clause, but my interest here with this question on meta is to purely understand how it works and perhaps make it easier for others to get to this information. It is based on my closed question, but it is not about my closed question. I believe Dale M answered this question on meta well and exactly in the spirit of my question, albeit not necessarily the answer I was hoping for.

Comment: @Andrei "*my interest here with this question on meta is to purely understand how it works*". This answer reads "*The question already has two of five required re-open votes*". Here I explained to you/others one factor (i.e., repetition) that tends to hinder reaching that number of reopen votes. "*I am also clueless of where you got it that I intended to repost my question.*" The 7th and  8th paragraphs in my answer (linked above) assess art. 14, thereby preemptively addressing/obviating your subsequent questions of whether art. 14 is enforceable in the event of landlord's noncompliance.

Comment: I absolutely appreciate you answering my first question, and I thank you for putting the effort into talking about it here. On top of it, I happen to agree with your opinions on my questions. Yet I don't know what else to do to steer this conversation on meta, away from my law question and onto the meta law question which is about how much time one should wait before reposting a massively edited question. Bear in mind that I'm not asking how long should **I** wait. I am sorry you misunderstood me. I just don't know how to make myself clear to you. Dale M got me though, and answered my question

Answer (score 1):

### Forever

The correct process is to not repost if the edited question remains closed. Unfortunately, edited questions do not attract the same number of eyeballs as new questions so this may mean some worthwhile questions stay on the cutting room floor for a long time; that’s just the way it is. Since this is just a general knowledge site and no one is or should be making decisions based on these Q&A it’s no great loss.

It's OK to delete your question and start over - the intention of the site is to have one definitive question so this works. Duplicate questions get closed but they leave a trail to the definitive question and so are left as they help in searching for the topic. Be aware that some questions cannot get deleted.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer.Thanks.It could probably be improved with a source, but I guess the Mod badge will have to do.I find the policy slightly harsh, but I can understand where it's coming from. I now realized that closed questions can be deleted. Do you know if this policy also covers deleted closed questions? It probably should because otherwise it looks like a loophole. But would it really be a loophole? I mean.. if someone deletes a bad closed question with no answers and later they ask a good question, is it really a repost or just 2 questions out of which the first is bad?

Comment: By all means, delete your question and repost another one. However, not all questions can be deleted - ones with upvoted answers for example.

Comment: I keep getting myself misunderstood. This is not necessarily about me. I am honestly curious about how it works. Indeed this curiosity was triggered by the situation I happen to be in, but I am just curious and I believe it may be good for others as well to have easier access to this information. But I find this information very useful, as I was not aware of it before.